# how to remove multiple columns in the csv if the row is having same values using awk command

Tags: awk

I have output like this

```
4567,4567
5436,5436
1234,5678
```

Expected output:

```
1234,5678
```

Tried below command but it is deleting the column not the row

```
awk -F, 'NF==2{NF-=1}NF<1{sub(/",.*/,"\"")}1' OFS=,
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my proposal with `sed`:

```
sed '/^\(.*\),\1$/d' file
```

Output:

```
1234,5678
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this

```
awk -F, '$1 != $2'
```

This works by comparing the first two comna-separsted fields. Each `awk`  statement has an implicit `{ print }` if no explicit statement is provided, and that is what is used here. The result is that an input line is printed only when the two fields do not match.

Comment: Tested it, works great. I had a similar requirement at work today. TQ


`❯ cat test.csv
4567,4567
5436,5436
1234,5678


❯ cat test.csv | awk -F, '$1 != $2'
1234,5678`

Comment: Tq @roaima, it worked!